# Массив пример дайте

Tags: c++

Дайте простой массив не динамический.
Пример. Если можнго с обясненем.

Comment: google ? array in c++ или static array c++ ну или любая книга по основам c++ -> оглавление -> массивы.... Но зачем вам думать, можно же задать вопрос, вы же наверное будущий программист

Answer (score 1):

Динамический массив- массив который Вы выделяете не на стеке, а в куче.

Основное приемущество динамического массива - возможность выделить память под размер массива, который будет определен во время работы программы, а не только на этапе компиляции.

Самый простой пример:
`int * dynamic_array = new int [n];` - это динамический массив, для которого выделено памяти для n - элементов.
В С++ для выделения новой памяти используется оператор `new` /`new[]`.

Память, которую вы выделяете с помощью этого оператора должна быть очищена Вами вручную с помощью оператора `delete/delete[]`.

То есть, если Вы выделили динамический массив с помощью оператора `new[]`, то следует вручную очистить память: `delete[] dynamic_array;`.

В случае работы с массивом на стеке вы можете создавать массив, размер которого должен быть известен на этапе компиляции. 

Пример такого массива: `int static_array[10];` - это не динамический массив.

В этом случае память будет очищена автоматически, при выходе из блока в котором находится этот массив или если будет освобождена память обьекта, в котором он хранился.  В случае с глобальным массивом, его память будет оч

Answer (score 0):

Простой нединамический массив `std::array<int, 10> array;`.